# Symbol string coercion

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, primitive-types, coercion

`Symbol() + ''` throws

> TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

While a known workaround is to use `String(Symbol())`.

This looks inconsistent with other primitives, including the ones that should almost never be coerced (`undefined` and `null`).

How exactly does `String` differ from `+ ''` (except it works)? Do specs explicitly specify that `String` should accept symbols? What were the motives to allow it in one way and disallow it in another?

Comment: Why?? A symbol is not meant to be exposed somewhere

Comment: @Jonasw: it still is a primitive type, hence it should work exactly like the other primitive types concering type coercion. That's quite an interesting question indeed. The only thing I can think of is that it is not enumerable, but it still can be casted to a string using `String`, so it really sounds like a mistery.

Comment: @Jonasw I encountered this problem the first time with error logging. A simple \`Object has no '${prop}'\` throws an error, unless you secure it with `String(prop)`. Not a very nice thing, but that's how it works.

Comment: @estus yeah that might be a usecase..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How exactly does String differ from + '' (except it works)? Do specs explicitly specify that String should accept symbols?

They differ in the aspect that `String()` has a case for a `Symbol()`, whereas the `+` operator (when used for concatenation) directly calls the `ToString()` operation which throws a `TypeError` exception for a `Symbol()`.

From `String()` spec:

> If NewTarget is undefined and Type(value) is Symbol, return SymbolDescriptiveString(value).

From `+` evaluation spec:

> If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then
>
> - Let lstr be ToString(lprim).
>
>   - ReturnIfAbrupt(lstr).
>   - Let rstr be ToString(rprim).
>   - ReturnIfAbrupt(rstr).
>   - Return the String that is the result of concatenating lstr and rstr.

Note: the definitions for `lprim` and `rprim` come from 10 previous steps in the evaluation process, which involve getting primitive types and values of the sides of the expression. I didn't include them to keep this post shorter. I have linked each specification I have referenced below.

From the `ToString()` output:

> Symbol:    Throw a TypeError exception.

As for your final question:

> What were the motives to allow it in one way and disallow it in another?

That's something for the writers at ECMA International.

[String() ES6 Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string-constructor-string-value)

[+ operator runtime evaluation ES6 Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

[ToString() Output behavior ES6 Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring)

Comment: I guess it would be appropriate to call it *ToString() operation* then, to not let the readers confuse it with toString() method.