# Template literals: how to perform substitution correctly?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

So I have a tag function:

```
var tagFunc = function(strings, ...expressions){

}
```

If I call it with:

```
tagFunc`sum is ${2+2}`
```

Then I assume that:

- `strings` is an array with two elements. `strings[0]` being `"sum is "` and `strings[1]` is the empty string that follows the expression (`""`).
- `expressions` is an array with one element only, the result of the expression `2+2` itself, therefore value `4`.
- `expressions` array will always have one item less than `strings` array.

Are my assumptions correct? How would one generate the final string inside the `tagFunc` correctly?

My attempt is

```js
var tagFunc = function(strings, ...expressions){
    var str = "";
  strings.forEach((string, i) => {
       str += string + (expressions[i]?expressions[i]:"");
  });
    return str;
}
console.log(tagFunc`sum is ${2+2}` === `sum is ${2+2}`) // true
```

Which seems to work:

Can I rely on my assumptions and continue with this logic?

Comment: I can't answer this question but I had no idea you could do that with template literals and functions. calling a function without the () with a template is cool. Thanks for the interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumptions are correct, this is how tags work, see also [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates).

There is a mistake in the code, this will ignore falsy expressions:

```
  strings.forEach((string, i) => {
       str += string + (expressions[i]?expressions[i]:"");
  });
```

Since it is expected that there is always final string and `strings` have 1 element more than `expressions`, it can be:

```
const tagFunc = ([initialString, ...strings], ...expressions) => expressions.reduce(
  (str, expression, i) => str + String(expression) + strings[i],
  initialString
);
```

It is preferable to have `String()` there because [`Symbol` cannot be implicitly coerced to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45354760/symbol-string-coercion).